# PHP ini_set open_basedir has no effect

Tags: php, php-ini, open-basedir, ini-set

I've got this problem on my Ubuntu + PHP 7.0.18 + Apache2:
In my php.ini is set the open_basedir = /var/www:/tmp. It works fine.
But in one web app I need to use another dirs to work with.
I am trying to set it through ini_set:

```
ini_set(
    'open_basedir',
    implode(
        PATH_SEPARATOR,
        array(
            __DIR__,
            '/media/hdd/backup/db'
        )
    )
);
```

But it has no any effect:

```
echo ini_get('open_basedir'); // shows /var/www:/tmp
```

If value of open_basedir in php.ini is empty, this code works fine.
Is it an expected behaviour or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open_basedir` can't be set *arbitrarily* at runtime via `ini_set()`, it can only be [tightened to a lower dir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir):

> As of PHP 5.3.0 open_basedir can be tightened at run-time. This means
>   that if open_basedir is set to /www/ in php.ini a script can tighten
>   the configuration to /www/tmp/ at run-time with ini_set(). When
>   listing several directories, you can use the PATH_SEPARATOR constant
>   as a separator regardless of the operating system.

Your call to `ini_set()` should be returning false to indicate that it has failed.